# How to block crawlers such as spyder/Nutch-2 from visiting a specific page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, web-crawler, nutch

I have a Windows client application that consumes a php page hosted in a shared commercial webserver.

In this **php** page I am returning an encrypted json. Also in this page I have a piece of code to keep track of which IPs are visiting this php page, and I have noticed that there is a `spyder/Nutch-2` crawler visiting this page.

I am wandering how is possible that a crawler could find a page that is not published in any search engines. I there a way to block crawlers from visiting this specific page?

Shall I use `.htaccess` file to configure it?

Comment: just ban the IP. Can be done in apache, but iptables or firewall would be prefered

Comment: @user574632 — how would you ban the spider from that particular URL (which would require inspecting the HTTP request) using iptables?

Comment: I thought he meant to just ban it completely

Comment: You can block crawlers ip or name based definiton in .htaccess file. But, crawler agent names or ip addresses can be change in time to time. Se my answer for further detail

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use a `.htaccess`. `robots.txt` is another option but some crawlers will ignore this. 
You can also block specific user agent strings. (They differ from crawler to crawler)

robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This example tells all robots to stay out of the website:
You can block specific directories

```
Disallow: /demo/
```

[More information about robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

Comment: Crawlers cannot ignore an .htaccess file, I think you are thinking of a robots.txt file.

Comment: Yes indeed my bad, I was referring to the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 2):

You can forbid specific crawlers by doing thatfollowing;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (spyder/Nutch-2) [NC]
#For multi block
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (spyder/Nutch-2|baidu|google|...) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=403,L]
```

That crawler, can change agent name, so this may not be the solution. You need to block that crawler by looking at ip address in need;

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from x.x.x.x
```

However, that bot can also change his ip address. This means, you need to track your access logs. And decide which agents to be blocked and add them to list manually

Answer (score 0):

You can ban the particular IP address with .htaccess file:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

where xxx represents IP address

Comment: yeah but the name and the ip of the spider can be changed. What is the solution in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Close. It would be better to use a [robots.txt](http://www.thesitewizard.com/archive/robotstxt.shtml) file. The page linked goes through why you would want to set one up and how to do so. In summary:

1. It avoids wasting server resources as the spiders and bots run the scripts on the page.
2. It can save bandwidth.
3. It removes clutter from the webstats.
4. You can fine-tune it to exclude only certain robots.

One caveat I should mention. Some spiders are coded to disregard the robots.txt file and will even examine it to see what you don't want them to visit. However, spiders from legit sources will obey the robots.txt directives.

Comment: `robots.txt` is not a solution. This file is not programatically blocks specific crawlers. Even if you define bot name in robots.txt file, it is up to specific crawler to cralw your website

Answer (score 0):

You could use .htaccess or another option would be to use php code. At the top of the php code simply put something like this:

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'spyder/Nutch-2') !== false) {
    die();
}
//rest of code here
```

Comment: But, static contents still be fetchable by crawlers. Since, apache directly serves static contend in default. You need to serve static content by using php also in order to make cralwer detected by your php code.

Comment: The OP was only talking about blocking a single php page that returns a json array, not the entire site.